# Razor tilde inside JavaScript String

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

I'm having trouble using the tilde " ~ " character available in Razor for setting the Application root, inside of a JavaScript string.  I'm using JavaScript to alter the href attribute of a link for different cases.  What's the proper way to use Razor to insert the application root on build?

The Closest I can get without an error is using this code:

> $('#ControlsSave').attr('href',
>   '@("~/@Page.Section/@Page.Subsection/")DVRDetails.cshtml?rating=' +
>   rating[ratingNum] )

Which generates this URL on build:

`href="~/@Page.Section/@Page.Subsection/DVRDetails.cshtml?rating=TV-Y"`

But it needs to be:

`href="localhost:1234/MyCustomSection/MyCustomSubsection/DVRDetails.cshtml?rating=TV-Y"`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Url.Content`:

```
    @Url.Content(
    string.Format(
        "~/{0}/{1}/DVRDetails.cshtml",
        Page.Section,
        Page.Subsection))
```

Complete usage should look like this:

```
$('#ControlsSave').attr('href', '@Url.Content(string.Format("~/{0}/{1}/DVRDetails.cshtml", Page.Section, Page.Subsection))' + '?rating=' + rating[ratingNum])
```

Comment: What do the bracket enclosed numbers do?

Comment: this did not work. Maybe I got the syntax wrong. I need an example of how to insert this into JavaScript just like my question. `$('#ControlsSave').attr('href', what do i put here? );`

Comment: @Ben, these are placeholders that `string.Format` uses to insert the parameters in order of appearance. For example here `{0}` will be substituted with `Page.Section`, `{1}` with `Page.Subsection`, `{2}` with `rating[ratingNum]`. You do not need to so this and can continue with plain concatenation, but `string.Format` is generally more readable.

Comment: it didn't work. Maybe because the ratings[ratingNum] portion is a JavaScript array.

Comment: @Ben, oh, that indeed is a different matter, did not know that. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks for you continual effort, but now I get this error, "The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @Ben, tha might have several causes. Have a look at this [thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1370964.aspx?CS0103+The+name+Url+does+not+exist+in+the+current+context) and the second answer there. In particular: make sure your view is `ViewPage` and that you have imported `System.Web.Mvc` namespace either in file or in web.config